# Imprimir una n cantidad de datos de un archivo csv PYTHON

Tags: python

Uso este codigo para leer el archivo csv, pero quiero solo sacar una parte no todo los datos.

```
with open('val.csv') as csvarchivo:
    entrada = csv.reader(csvarchivo)
    for reg in entrada:
        print(reg)
```

Resultado: de los 100 datos por ejemplo quisiera obtener los 7 primeros:

```
['1;1;5']
['1;2;5']
['1;3;5']
['1;4;5']
['1;5;5']
['1;7;1']
['1;11;1']
```

Comment: cambia `for reg in entrada:` a `for reg in entrada[:7]:` :)

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que con "datos" te refieras a las filas, teniendo en cuenta que `csv.reader` **retorna un iterador** no puedes realizar un slicing sobre el directamente, tendrías que crear una lista o tupla con todas las líneas primero:

```
rows = list(entrada)
primeras_siete = rows[:7]
```

Ahora bien, esto **implica cargar el fichero al completo en memoria** lo que debes evitar si no es necesario. Si quieres obtener las x primeras filas o un fragmento del mismo eficientemente la solución pasa por consumir el generador llamado manualmente a `next` x veces (comprobando que no se ha agotado el mismo) o usar `enumerate` para obtener solo aquellas filas que nos interesen:

```
import csv


with open('val.csv') as csvarchivo:
    entrada = csv.reader(csvarchivo)
    for index, row in enumerate(entrada):
        print(row)
        if index == 6:
            break
```

Modificando el condicional puede obtener solo filas con un determinado indice, un rango, etc.

No obstante, una opción más simple que todo esto es usar `itertools.islice` que hace lo anterior por ti:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice


with open('val.csv') as csvarchivo:
    entrada = csv.reader(csvarchivo)
    rows = list(islice(entrada, 7))
```

Dónde `rows` es una lista que contendrá las primeras 7 filas del fichero (o las que contenga si tiene menos de 7).

Para solo imprimirlas (si es que tiene alguna utilidad por si solo) basta con:

```
with open('val.csv') as csvarchivo:
    entrada = csv.reader(csvarchivo)
    for row in islice(entrada, 7):
        print(row)
```

`itertools.islice` te permite realizar un rebanado "slicing" sobre un iterador (cualquier iterable en realidad) al igual que el slicing sobre las listas o tuplas, con la excepción de no permitir indexado negativo (esto implica conocer la longitud del iterador, lo que implica consumirlo previamente), retorna otro iterador sobre el fragmento concreto del iterable:

- `islice(entrada, 10, 21)` -> desde línea 10 hasta 20 (indices comienzan en 0)
- `islice(entrada, 10, 21, 2)` -> desde línea 10 hasta la 20 pero una si otra no (filas pares).

Ten en cuenta que **iterar sobre un iterador por el método que sea lo "consume"**, es decir si vuelves a hacer `rows = list(islice(entrada, 5))` después de `rows = list(islice(entrada, 7))` no obtienes las primeras 5 líneas del fichero, obtienes las 5 lineas siguientes a la séptima (que fue dónde se quedó `rows = list(islice(entrada, 7))`).

Comment: @FJSevillas Gracias amigo me sirvio de mucho.